# Virtual PC changing user

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, user-profiles, windows-xp-mode, active-directory

I have Windows Virtual PC running XP Mode.

On a current local user `<Mark>` I have put the PC on a domain `<mydomain>`.

Virtual PC works but I struggle to get the image I have working on the domain profile. I can create a new image and it works but getting the image that is in `./<mark>` to work on `<mark.mydomain>` is the issue

I have used the *Add a virtual hard disk* step of the virtual machine setup, selected *Use an existing virtual hard disk* and then clicked the *Browse* button. I located and selected the Windows XP Mode base.vhd file that I was modifying earlier, which is located in the `C:\Program Files\Windows XP Mode\` folder.

I say modifying earlier because I have changed the ownership and permissions and Windows XP Mode base.vhd and selected properties. To remove the read-only attribute that is preventing us from modifying this file, by Clicking  the Security tab and then click the Advanced button.

Have I missed something? When I run using this .VHD the system creates a new image. Is it not the .vhd file that holds the old image from `<mark>` user, or is there a registration or config file that goes with this file to make the old image work?

I can still run the original image as the ./ user.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  You'd have better luck on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VHD you were targetting **isn't** the same VHD you built under the domain profile.

The VHD under Program Files is a image Virtual PC uses to build a working XP installation.

Your domain profile's XP Mode VHD is under %UserProfiles%\Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the file is hidden in local/app folder and you can then mount once copied to new profile.. found local/app folder as there are the default VHD and local VHD